# Reload page redirect to main page with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router

When I try reload subpage app redirect me to main page.
When I type in browser subpage (example: `/about`) app redirect me to main page.
It's my router component in **App.js**.

P.S I use arrow functions in React.

```
<Router>
        <Header />
        <Container history={props.history}>
          <Route exact path="/" component={SelectLogin} />
          <Route path="/selectlogin" component={SelectLogin} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/register" component={RegisterPanel} />
          <Route path="/addcomment" component={AddComment} />
          <Route path="/findposts" component={FindPosts} />
          <Route path="/lostposts" component={LostPosts} />
          <Route path="/posts" component={Posts} />
          <Route path="/lostpost" component={LostPost} />
          <Route path="/findrequest" component={FindRequest} />
          <Route path="/lostrequest" component={LostRequest} />
          <Route path="/requestsummary" component={Summary} />
          <Route path="/logincode" component={LoginCodePanel} />
          <Route path="/logindata" component={LoginDataPanel} />
          <Route path="/adminpanel" component={AdminPanel} />
          <Route path="/editprofile" component={EditProfile} />
          <Route path="/userpanel" component={UserPanel} />
          <Route path="/userposts/:id" component={UserPosts} />
          <Route path="/editpost" component={EditPost} />
        </Container>
      </Router>
```

Comment: try to add ```exact``` for example into Route that have ```path="/about"``` @mattxml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you missed `<Switch />` component in the middle.

Try the following:

```
<Router>
   <Switch>
        <Header />
        <Container history={props.history}>
          <Route exact path="/" component={SelectLogin} />
          { /* all the other routes */ }
          <Route path="/editpost" component={EditPost} />
        </Container>
   </Switch>
</Router>
```

See a basic routing example [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start/1st-example-basic-routing).

I hope this helps!